# Javascript to hide an element based on the contents of an active-class element elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide some elements on a page based on the contents of the specific element in a navbar (formed as a list) which has an active class. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
var element=document.querySelector('ul.nav > li.active')
if((typeof element != 'undefined')?element.innerText == "Page 1")
{
   document.getElementById("options1").style.display = 'none';

}
```

And the HTML that I need to work with is basically as follows.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
 <li class="active">
  <a href="#section-page-1">Page 1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#section-page-2">Page 2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#section-page-3">Page 3</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div id="options1">Stuff Here</div>
```

The behavior that I want is that when Page 1 is active, the `<div>` is hidden, and when all other pages are active, the `<div>` is visible.

I've tried a bunch of closely related things from stack overflow but haven't managed to get anything to work yet.

Thanks! I'm pretty new to javascript.

Comment: Hi Lazzer Tag, i didn't understand your question , are you trying the create tabs  could you had screenshots what to do you want to achieve

Comment: `document.querySelector(....)` does not work dynamically, it just returns the DOM element corresponding to the css selector when it is executed. If subsequently another element corresponds to this selector, the returned value will not change and will remain on the starting point

Answer (score 1):

You can get the # called by your link with `window.location.hash` is JS like

```js
if (window.location.hash === "#section-page-1") {
  document.getElementById("options1").style.display = 'none';
}
```

This should work